# More efficient way to set up independent random() generation in p5.js / Javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When i try to create some random generations, i have to write many lines of random(); such as :

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  var widths = 30;
  
  //How to simply these codes? Thanks
  random1 = random(0,300);
  random2 = random(0,300);
  random3 = random(0,300);
  random4 = random(0,300);
  random5 = random(0,300);
  random6 = random(0,300);
  
  
  circle(random1,random2,widths);
  circle(random3,random4,widths);
  circle(random5,random6,widths);
  
}
```

Doesn't have to be for the circle position scenario above. Just would like to ask whether there are other ways to perform the same generation process in a more simple way in P5.js or Javascript in general.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not use a loop? `for(let i=0; i<3; ++i) { circle(random(0,300),random(0,300),widths); }`

Comment: Okay thanks. It worked